# Get the pandas dataframe first row with index

Tags: python, pandas

Recently I have started using Pandas in my work to handle the data obtained by some sensors
I have a dictionary with the sensor values in the following format:

```py
data={
  2019-10-23 00:00:00: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    ...
    keyN: valueN
  },
  2019-10-23 00:00:03: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    ...
    keyN: valueN
  },
  ...
}
```

I create a pandas dataframe:

```py
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index")
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```py
Whole Dataframe:
                            co        no2  ...  temperature  illuminance
2019-10-23 00:00:43  298.66458   0.000000  ...    15.498970          0.0
2019-10-23 00:00:44  305.92203   0.000000  ...    15.498970          0.0
2019-10-23 00:00:37  298.66458   3.456714  ...    15.498970          0.0
2019-10-23 00:00:50  305.92203   0.000000  ...    15.498970          0.0
2019-10-23 00:00:45  305.92203   0.000000  ...    15.498970          0.0
...                        ...        ...  ...          ...          ...
2019-10-23 23:33:59  327.05542   0.000000  ...    14.740597          0.0
2019-10-23 23:38:37  296.85214   0.000000  ...    14.687190          0.0
2019-10-23 23:43:38  289.69748   0.000000  ...    14.612421          0.0
2019-10-23 23:50:38  282.21335  15.672545  ...    14.526970          0.0
2019-10-23 23:54:44  297.21220   0.000000  ...    14.505608          0.0
```

Now I need to be able to get the values of the first row, I tried using `.iloc[0]` and `to_dict()` to get a dictionary to send through an api rest:

```py
selected_value = dataframe.iloc[0].to_json()
```

prints this:

```py
Selected value:
{"co":298.66458,"no2":3.456714,"o3":53.318943,"so2":0.0,"humidity":65.13771,"pm1":0.0198951,"pm10":0.0209116,"pm25":0.0209116,"temperature":15.49897,"illuminance":0.0}
```

But it doesn't return the index, I'd like to get something like this (or at least include the index anyway):

```py
{"2019-10-23 00:00:43": 
 {
   "co":298.66458, 
   "no2":3.456714, 
   "o3":53.318943, 
   "so2":0.0, 
   "humidity":65.13771,
   "pm1":0.0198951,
   "pm10":0.0209116,
   "pm25":0.0209116,
   "temperature":15.49897,
   "illuminance":0.0
  }
}
```

Any way to do this?

PD: Indicate that I perform some intermediate procedures to obtain the sensor values every 10 minutes using the `between_time` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `head` instead like:

```
# example data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(2), 'b':range(2,4)}, 
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2018','02/01/2018']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

print (df.head(1).to_json(orient='index'))
{"2018-01-01 00:00:00":{"a":0,"b":2}}
#or to_dict maybe
print (df.head(1).to_dict(orient='index'))
{'2018-01-01 00:00:00': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you selected the index, it doesn't return it

If you want the index to be part of the data, you can always set it:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'timestamp'},inplace=True)
```

Doing `df.iloc[0]` will then also return `timestamp` as every other column

If you don't want it to be part of the data, you can always directly build what you want by using `dataframe.index`:

```
import json
json.dumps({df.index[0]:df.iloc[0].to_dict()})
```